# The single quote problem

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a .Net developer.

I blog at http://www.ruchitsurati.net which is my personal blog. Recently I'm facing a stupid issue that is driving me nuts. In my wordpress blog admin, I write my post and then hit save.All works fine but upon Save,all single-quotes are doubled to what is given as input.

Ex: The original text **I'm writing this post** is converted to **I''m writing this post**, And next time when I save it, it becomes **I''''m writing this post**

I have no idea, what is causing this problem. Is there anything to do with encoding while saving ? Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
php_value magic_quotes_gpc 0
php_flag magic_quotes_runtime 0
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: I tried this,it gave me 500 internal error so had to roll back.